# Bing Maps API - Geometry Data

Tags: geospatial, bing, bing-api, bing-maps

Is it possible to get geometry/vector data from Bing Maps, such as a set of points that describe the shape of the continent of Australia, in a certain zoom level? I couldn't find anything about it, except for this [discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/onedrive/en-US/a406b9ef-5e87-4ee7-b51e-30503e1681de/are-we-able-to-get-bing-map-geometry-data-and-draw-our-own-map-critically-needed?forum=vemapcontroldev) from 2009, which states that it is impossible.

So I wonder if anything had changed since then... I would be glad to know about any other possible solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: There are some free, open source solutions, such as http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php and http://www.naturalearthdata.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to retrieve such information by using the Bing Maps Spatial Data Services with the Geodata API. See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306801.aspx

And you can find examples here:

http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/06/25/retrieving-boundaries-from-the-bing-spatial-data-services-preview/